# Close-button selector won't fire without global variable

Tags: swift, uibutton, action, instance, selector

My root viewController contains a variable to another class and a button to show that class' view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myBoxView = BoxView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showBoxView), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(btn)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.5, constant: 0))
    }

}

extension ViewController {

    @objc func showBoxView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
//      let myBoxView = BoxView()
        myBoxView.showView()
    }

}
```

The other class conforms to NSObject and has another button to close it's view:

```
class BoxView: NSObject {

    let boxView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 300, height: 300))
    let closeBtn = UIButton()

    func showView() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeBoxView), for: .touchUpInside)
            closeBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            closeBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            boxView.addSubview(closeBtn)
            boxView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: closeBtn, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            boxView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: closeBtn, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

            boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            window.addSubview(boxView)
            boxView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}

extension BoxView {

    @objc func closeBoxView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.boxView.alpha = 0
            self.boxView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}
```

*The code has been simplified.*

This all works fine *until*...
(IE. When one hits the root button, the selector (showBoxView) is fired and the BoxView is shown. Then one hits the close button (closeBoxView fires) and it fades away. Then normal operation resumes.)

When I don't use the global variable (myBoxView) and create a new instance, the class' close button's selector (closeBoxView) won't fire. Even though the boxView is displayed.

(IE. I insert `let myBoxView = BoxView()` to the top of the "showBoxView" method)

**Why isn't the selector (closeBoxView) called, without using it's instance (from root VC)?**

PS. I have done this programmatically by adding to AppDelegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions":

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
```

Comment: there is no reference to the boxView for the UIWindow to be able to run the hit test against. while you rendered it inside the method, everything got perfectly displayed, after the execution of method, there is no reference left.

Comment: @AppleCiderGuy Of course. I should've of discovered that!